# Como colocar o caminho de uma imagem com comprimento restringido na base de dados

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Ola,
Eu tenho uma variavel do tipo string que deve guardar as imagens, mas ele tem comprimento 40 e ao tentar colocar o caminho da erro. 
Eu tenho uma pasta no wwwroot onde guardo as imagens e qeria guardar na variavel o caminho de forma a usar a variavel e ela me devolver a imagem correspondente a esse utilizador. 
Tenho este codigo no controller :

```
 string caminho = Path.Combine(_hostEnviroment.ContentRootPath, "wwwroot\\Fotos_utilizadores");

        string nome_ficheiro = Path.GetFileName(fotografia.FileName);
        string caminho_completo = Path.Combine(caminho, nome_ficheiro);

        FileStream fs = new FileStream(caminho_completo, FileMode.Create);
        fotografia.CopyTo(fs);
        professores.Fotografia = nome_ficheiro;
        fs.Close();
```

E na view um formulario :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="RegistarProfessor">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Nome" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Nome" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Nome" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Email" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Fotografia" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Fotografia" type="file" accept=".gif, .jpg, .bmp" class="form-control" />
            @*<span asp-validation-for="Fotografia" class="text-danger"></span>*@
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="hidden" name="fotografia" value="0" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group form-check">
            @*<label class="form-check-label">
            <input class="form-check-input" asp-for="Sexo" /> @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Sexo)
        </label>*@
            <label asp-for="Sexo" class="control-label"></label>
            <select asp-for="Sexo" class="form-control">
                <option value="true">Feminino</option>
                <option value="false">Masculino</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Especialidade" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Especialidade" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Especialidade" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Password" class="control-label"></label>
            <input type="password" asp-for="Password" id="password" placeholder="password" class="form-control" />
            <input type="button" id="showPassword" value="Mostrar" class="button" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Estado" class="control-label"></label>
            <input type="text" value="1" asp-for="Estado" disabled="disabled" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Estado" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

Alguem sabe como posso resolver isso ? De forma a guardar na base de dados o caminho da imagem ?

Comment: Qual o erro? Quais validações são feitas no seu modelo?

Comment: Também não é necessário repetir a pergunta, é possível editar a sua pergunta antiga.

Comment: Qual é o valor atribuído à professores.Fotografia?

Comment: @tvdias o valor atribuido a professores.Fotografia é  o nome da fotografia > professores.Fotografia = nome_ficheiro;

Comment: Sim, e qual é o valor nos seus testes?

Comment: por exemplo, cross_fit.jpg

Comment: E qual é o erro apresentado?

Comment: nao é um erro especifico, apenas qeria guardar o caminho para a imagem la de forma a poder usar a imagem correspondente aqele professor

Comment: "ao tentar colocar o caminho da erro". não entendi. Há erro ou não há?

Comment: "SqlException: String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated. " Aparece este erro

Comment: O erro é bem claro... Nesse caso é importante confirmar o tamanho das colunas  na base de dados e todos os dados passados. Coloque um breakpoint no save do EF e verifique exatamente todos os valores passados antes de serem gravados na base de dados. Creio que não há nada a ser feito além disso.

Comment: O problema é que a String tem tamanho 40 e é pequena, nao é possivel guardar apenas o nome e a extensao ?

Comment: Vc diz que a coluna tem tamanho 40 e está enviando "cross_fit.jpg" para a base de dados, então ou vc não está enviando esse valor, ou a coluna não tem esse tamanho ou o problema é em outra coluna. Seja qual for o caso, é impossível de ser adivinhado. É preciso conferir todas as partes.

Comment: dá 40 com o path inteiro... mas porque você simplesmente não aumenta o tamanho da coluna no banco de dados?

Comment: Nao estou a conseguir atualizar a base de dados

Comment: @LeandroAngelo da erro que uma das  tabelas ja existe na base de dados

Comment: Só se você está tentando criar a tabela de novo, o que você precisa é alterar sua estrutura.

Comment: Sim e eu para altera-la no package manager console escrevo update-database e aparece este erro : There is already an object named 'Aulas_Grupo' in the database.